# Spring beans in testing

Tags: spring, testing, webdriver

I have a Spring bean in applicationContext.xml

```
    <bean id = "mailUser" class="com.company.application.domain.User">
    <property name="username" value="${mail.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mail.password}" />
```

I would like to autowire it's contents to my test class like

```
@Autowired
private User mailUser;

@Test
public void signIn() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://mailservice.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(getMailUser().getUsername());
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(getMailUser().getPassword());
    driver.findElement(By.className("btn")).click();
```

This however causes a NullPointerException. I see

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.company.app.SignInTest.signIn(SignInTest.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
```

Line points to username line. Does anyone know how to fix it right? I'm new to this.

Comment: What is the full stacktrace of this `NullPointerException`? Which line?

Comment: The get username line. I think it simply does not get the values from the bean.

Comment: It can throw NPE in at least 4 places in that line, question edit + full stacktrace really appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to import your XML configuration into the class using the @ImportResource annotation.

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@Configuration
@ContextConfiguration( classes = { TestClass.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class )
@ImportResource( { "classpath:resources/applicationConfig.xml" } )
public class TestClass {}
```

Comment: Do you have to place the applicationContext somewhere specific? I have it under WEB-INF.

Comment: It needs to be accessible from the classpath. In my example I put the applicationContext.xml files under resource/ since that is what a lot of the documentation does now. For test cases, I put the XML specific configuration in the same location as the test source file, in that case you should be able to reference it by "classpath:applicationContext.xml".

Comment: I put them into same package but still get an error that the xml file does not exist. I'm sure I typed right.

Comment: Sorry, my comment is wrong! If you do `@import( { "applicationContext.xml" })` the `applicationContext.xml` should be at the root of your package tree. If you want to store the `applicationContext.xml` in the same package as your test class as I recommended, you need to put the full package path. For example `uk.me.bjw.tests.MyTest.class` would have an `@ImportResource( { "uk/me/bjw/tests/applicationContext.xml" })`.

Comment: Do you know what is the path to import resource from Netbeans test packages?

Answer (score 0):

When Spring autowires, it looks for a constructor or "getter" in which to use to autowire (it also says it does it by field, but I've never had any luck with it). Easiest way to fix your problem is to do the following:

```
public class P{

    private User mailUser;

    @Autowired
    public void setUser(User mailUser) {
        this.mailUser = mailUser;
    }
```